# PHP Library outputs useless information to log/stdout

Tags: php, wpf, wso2

I have wpf / wso2 installed, and every time I run the php executable, I get garbage output from it:

```
[joshua@host1 ~]$ php
[Mon Feb 27 11:50:43 2012] [info]  Cannot find path /srv/joshua/wsf_c/services.
[Mon Feb 27 11:50:43 2012] [info]  [rampart] rampart_mod initialized
[Mon Feb 27 11:50:43 2012] [info]  [rahas]Rahas module initialized
```

How can I suppress/disable this output. I cannot read the output from my scripts due to these lines being generated repeatedly.

Comment: @Jan wpf/wso2 is a SOAP server and PHP language library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be redirected to a log by the setting:

```
wsf.log_path="/path/to/logs"
```

in php.ini

They are generated by the setting:

```
wsf.log_level = 3
```